# Adobe Wallaby - Flash-to-HTML5 conversion tool

Tags: flash, html

today I received a video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ryZP00_KhYE about adobe wallaby,  it seems to be a new conversion tool from flash to html5 but I have some questions that I cannot find information at the moment:
- Does anyone knows when it will be available?
- Why html5 seems to be the new choice when flash leads webdevelopment with strong present in platforms such as youtube?.
brgds. sebastian.

Comment: Your first question is valid (I don't have an answer); your second question has been answered/debated a bajillion times: in short, HTML5 is a new iteration of HTML that encapsulates a few features (e.g. Video) that previously relied on proprietary languages (e.g. Flash). Flash is not being replaced, HTML is just being extended.

Comment: thank you zzzz, the main reason I asked it because most of the info talk about new developments for new devices (tablets, phones) but for the moment only few browsers display html5 correctly.  It seems to be more like a promise compared with rich media at this moment in reference to all the functionalities rich media offer in terms of statistics and usage. the product was presented as the possibility of flash to continue on the road when - for the moment as all in technology - is the stronger solution available.. once again, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey its now avilable and i've actually made a video on it so hope you start using it i think its one of the coolest new adobe products out there ;)
here is the link:
http://everythingfla.com/quickies/wallaby